# undefined reference to 'cv::viz::Viz3d::Viz3d(std::string&const)'

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have run my opencv code with qtcreator and i have gotten this answer when i tried to use the Viz library.

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp>

#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

#include <opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp>

#include <opencv2/viz/vizcore.hpp>

    /// Create a window
    viz::Viz3d myWindow("Viz Demo");

    /// Start event loop
    myWindow.spin();

    /// Event loop is over when pressed q, Q, e, E
    printf("First event loop is over\n");

    /// Access window via its name
    viz::Viz3d sameWindow = viz::getWindowByName("Viz Demo");

    /// Start event loop
    sameWindow.spin();

    /// Event loop is over when pressed q, Q, e, E
    printf("Second event loop is over\n");

    /// Event loop is over when pressed q, Q, e, E
    /// Start event loop once for 1 millisecond
    sameWindow.spinOnce(1, true);
    while(!sameWindow.wasStopped())
    {
        /// Interact with window

        /// Event loop for 1 millisecond
        sameWindow.spinOnce(1, true);
    }

    /// Once more event loop is stopped
    printf("Last event loop is over\n");
```

i have installed the 2.4.9 version of opencv with Ubuntu 12.10 and i think they are compatible.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you linking with the appropriate library? `-l<opencv-lib-name-goes-here>`?

Comment: the problem was what u said Praetorian thank u!

Answer (score 2):

If the library is installed

- go to Project->Properties->Settings->GCC C++ Linker-> Libraries
- add opencv_viz  to your libraries (screenshot)

[image: screenshot]

- save and build project

Answer (score 1):

First check if the library **libopencv_viz.so** is installed properly in your system. If yes, then add **-lopencv_viz** while compiling the cpp file. Ideally **"pkg-config --libs opencv"** should include it.

Thanks.